# Selecting all features except one using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, query, select-by-attribute

Using QGIS 2.18. I have 346 polygons on a layer and I want to display all but one.

In this instance I wish to run a query using field ONSCode but show all except 17UB.

I have been trying to use NOT but in the wrong context and get errors.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

How about `"ONScode" != '17UB'`

`!=` means "not equal to".

Answer (score 7):

Easy way: Select `'17UB'` manually, then invert the selected features.

By code: `"ONScode" NOT LIKE '17UB'`

Comment: `LIKE` also does wildcard matching which makes the operator slightly slower (and behave slightly differently) than `=` and `!=`.  For for the string `'ABC 123'` the patterns `'ABC 123'`, `'A%'`, `'%3'` and `'%C 1%'` all match.  The pattern `'10%'` matches the string `'10%'` but also the string `'100%'`.  The character `_` matches any single character.  In QGIS 3 and later you can match a literal `%` or `_` with `\\\\%` and `\\\\_`. Interestingly, in QGIS wildcards are implemented as regexes under the hood; this means using regexp_match should actually be slightly cheaper than simple wildcards!